# How to use Javascript variables from a wider scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am writing a simple `WebSocket` application with `socketio`. There are 2 socket events that I can implement, on connect and on message. The first one takes the socket as parameter(client) and second takes the data sent from client. So I could write it this way to use the socket variable in on message event:

```
WebSocketNoaListener.onClientConnect = function(socket){
var soc = socket;
socket.on("message", function(msg){
         console.log("i can use message: "+msg);
         console.log("and the socket: "+soc.id);
    });
socket.on("disconnect", WebSocketNoaListener.onClientDisconnect);
}
```

But i want to separate my functions for better readability:

```
WebSocketNoaListener.onClientConnect = function(socket){
var soc = socket;
socket.on("message", WebSocketNoaListener.onClientMessage);
socket.on("disconnect", WebSocketNoaListener.onClientDisconnect);
}


WebSocketNoaListener.onClientMessage = function(){...
```

I would need to use the `soc` variable in a scope outside the function that receives `socket`. Is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "outerscope" here?

Comment: @JaredPar I've taken the liberty of rewording "outerscope"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really do something like this instead of polluting the global space (moreover, the solution given in the two other answers wont be able to handle two simultaneous connections, because `soc` is overridden at each connection).

```
WebSocketNoaListener.onClientMessage = function(soc, msg){
  console.log("i can use message: " + msg);
  console.log("and the socket: " + soc.id);
};
WebSocketNoaListener.onClientDisconnect = function(soc, event){
  console.log("not implemented in question");
};
WebSocketNoaListener.onClientConnect = function(socket){
  socket.on("message", WebSocketNoaListener.onClientMessage.bind(this, socket));
  socket.on("disconnect", WebSocketNoaListener.onClientDisconnect.bind(this, socket));
}
```

Comment: well you are right cause in the above case, the global socket variable is not going to point to the right socket instance which belongs to the event. The above cases answer my question but don't solve my problem. "This" scope points indeed the socket itself so your answer is the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `soc` outside of your onClientConnection function.

```
var soc;

WebSocketNoaListener.onClientConnect = function(socket){
  soc = socket;
  socket.on("message", WebSocketNoaListener.onClientMessage);
  socket.on("disconnect", WebSocketNoaListener.onClientDisconnect);
}
```

`soc` can now be accessed outside of onClientConnect.

Answer (score -2):

ok here is the websocket specific ultimate answer;

```
WebSocketNoaListener.onClientConnect = function(socket){
    var soc = socket;
    socket.on("message", WebSocketNoaListener.onClientMessage);
    socket.on("disconnect", WebSocketNoaListener.onClientDisconnect);
}

WebSocketNoaListener.onClientMessage = function(msg){
    console.log("this is the message "+msg);
    console.log("and this is the id of the socket "+this.id);
    //'this' points here the socket itself
}
```

Comment: And no reflection on why, and what was wrong in the first place.

Comment: I'm sorry if my answer totally missed the point of your question. I've deleted it. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7878346/revisions